# jwt token validation on main page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

before i started working with reactJS i was using express sessions (with expressJS of course) to determine whether user was authenticated or not, my middleware was passed in /profile URL like this `router.use('/profile', middleware, require('./profilePageFile'))` and if user was not authenticated i was redirecting to login page with simple code

```
if(!req.session.user){
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

i tried to use redirecting with react too but since react has it's own routing system (react-router-dom) and express is only needed for creating APIs when i was logging in /profile url it was still showing me page content and redirecting me after xxx milliseconds later, and i think it would be better practice if i have my profile page and main page on default url  ( 'domain.com/' ), as i see many websites are using this technique including Facebook, at this point i was trying to make something like this: if user has not token or token expired, don't display some "hello user" button, otherwise display it. my only problem is that i do not know how to do that. 
if i have boolean in my react state called isAuthenticated or something like this which determines whether user is authenticated or not according to the header that i send from server-side, it would be bad practice for security, i think, and also when i tried that, it did not work anyway.  at this point only thing that i can do is to pass req.userId to client if token exists. this works but it is not enough, if anyone got the point i will be glad if i get help
here is my middleware code

```
const guard = (req, res, next) => {
  const token =
    req.body.token ||
    req.query.token ||
    req.headers["x-access-token"] ||
    req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).send({ auth: false });
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({
          message: err.message
        });
      }

      req.userId = decoded.id;
      res.status(200).send({ auth: true });
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: what can i do instead of sending {auth:false} ?

Comment: What are you asking specifically? How to write the JWT checking middleware or how to optionally display components in React?

Comment: basically yes. how to write the JWT checking middleware

Comment: can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made two changes to your code.

```
const guard = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.body.token ||
        req.query.token ||
        req.headers['x-access-token'] ||
        req.cookies.token;

    if (!token) {
        // Authentication failed: Token missing
        return res.status(401).send({ auth: false })
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            // Authentication failed: Token invalid
            return res.status(401).send({
                auth: false,
                message: err.message
            })
        }

        req.userId = decoded.id
        next()
    })
}
```

First, inside the `if(err)` condition I have changed the status code to `401` because if the token is invalid, it will raise the error here.

Secondly, I have removed the `res.status(200).send({auth:true})` from the bottom of the function.
This is because the middleware should pass on to the route (which we are trying to protect with the JWT check) to respond. This was responding to the request before it got to the actual route.

Comment: you did not get my point sadly. i will try something and if i will not be succeed i will explain my problem in more details

Comment: I will leave this here for now, but if you could update your question to highlight a  specific question or problem you have.

Comment: can we talk in chat? because it is hard to explain here

Comment: oh, don't worry about it anymore i solved problem, (i think)